# Jquery UI datepicker year dropdown blank in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery UI 1.8.7 year dropdown contains no value. Works fine with all other browsers and even IE9, but IE is giving me hard time.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are there some errors in console?

Comment: post your code ..to know about `yearRange` , `minDate` , `maxDate`..

Comment: There are still some open bugs in the datepicker for IE8, and it doesn't look like they'll be fixed as noone really cares about IE8 anymore, but I haven't seen that one before, the years should show. What version of jQuery are you using, jQuery UI 1.8.7 was released for jQuery 1.4, and that's half a decade ago

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin : no error in console.

Comment: @adeneo: jquery version 1.7.1, this is an old code, I am fixixng bugs, cant take the risk of updating library as it might break various other dependencies